# Opening Shortcuts through Command Prompt Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

Solved, check the marked solution

In a Windows `cmd` shell, the command `start SomeShortcut.lnk` normally opens the program if the command is entered in the correct directory, like `start Surfshark.lnk`.

But the same shortcut does not seem to work for shortcuts which have spaces in their names. Like `start LibreOffice Writer.lnk`.

Even with `start "LibreOffice Writer.lnk"` it opens an additional terminal window:

Is there any way this problem can be eliminated. Or should I make some changes in the command?

Image of the Additional Command Prompt on `start "LibreOffice Writer.lnk"`:

> [image]

After the Command Is Executed:

> [image]

Comment: @john. It won't. See my answer for the explanation of why it won't

Comment: Enclosing all in quotes did not appear to work for the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### start "LibreOffice Writer.lnk" -  it opens an additional terminal window

That is because the **first** quoted argument passed to `start` is a window title.

The following command should behave as expected:

```
start "" "LibreOffice Writer.lnk"
```

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
> ```
>
> Key:
>
> ```
> title       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
> path        Starting directory.
> command     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
> parameters  The parameters passed to the command.
> ```

...

> Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like `"My Script"` or
> just a pair of empty quotes `""`
>
> According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but
> depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is
> omitted.

Source [Start - Start a program - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)